# CSS grid with sticky nav

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid, sticky

I am stuck with CSS grids

I want to make a webpage, that has

- a sticky nav (with `top: 15px;` )
- full screen "scenes" (they take up the remaining space under the nav).

So the height of the nav and the content should be 100vh

At every scene, the top ~10% is the nav and the rest is the content

**Here is a blueprint**
[image]

Comment: Do you have some HTML or CSS written? maybe what you tried is close enough and with some suggestion it may work.

Answer (score 1):

If any1 watches this in the future

```
main
    display: grid
    grid-template-rows: auto // height of nav
    grid-auto-rows: 100vh // fullscreen scenes
```

On sticky nav

```
main
   // all props from above
   --nav-position-top: 15px
   padding-top: var(--nav-position-top)
nav
   position: sticky
   top: var(--nav-position-top)
```

[image: Example]